# Menu feito no Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como centralizar um menu feito no Pingendo Bootstrap?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Boletim Online</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body draggable="true">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></a>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" draggable="true">Administrador</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li>
              <a href="cadastroturmas.php">Turmas</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: posta o código de como tá teu cabeçalho ou coisa parecida pra podermos te ajudar melhor

Comment: Por favor, utilize mais detalhes em sua pergunta, para que possamos entender o que você utilizando e o que você precisa fazer e também gostaríamos de saber o que você já tentou.

Answer (score 2):

Ajusta no css como descrito aqui que acredito resolver o seu problema:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-center">
    <li>
        <a href="cadastroturmas.php">Turmas</a>
    </li>
```

```
.navbar{
    padding : 0 25px;
}

.nav-center{
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwvLm6tg/2/

Importante que seja com percentual para manter a responsividade.